# obfuscate font file with IDPF standard in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have to obfuscate and de-obfuscate font files- .otf and .ttf files with IDPF algorithm.   i have got this code to obfuscate a file in java

```
public void serialize(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
            try {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int len;
                    InputStream in = source.getInputStream();
                    boolean first = true;
                    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            if( first && mask != null ) {
                                    first = false;
                                    for( int i = 0 ; i < 1040 ; i++ ) {
                                            buffer[i] = (byte)(buffer[i] ^ mask[i%mask.length]);
                                    }
                            }
                            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            out.close();
    }
```

is there any requirement of encryption key as in this code encryption key is not used. please guide me to how to get started

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need an encryption key because it's not encrypting the file, it's obfuscating it. If you want to encrypt a file, and then decrypt it there are quite a few built-in classes in the `.net` framework for this exact purpose, and they take an encryption key.

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) namespace.It contains many classes that allow you to use different algorithms for encrypting and decrypting data.

Furthermore, never write your own encryption code, as it will almost certainly be breakable (unless you're a genius, very conscientious, and have nothing else more important to do for the next year or two).